# Azure .NET v4 SDK Proxy Configuration in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, azure

I'm using the newer v4.x version of the Azure .NET SDKS - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/4.1.0

In my case this is to access Key Vault secrets but the question probably applies globally. When using the above nuget package to retrieve a secret through a .NET Core 3.1 app, all seems to work OK.

```
var credential = new ClientSecretCredential("<TENANT_ID>", "<CLIENT_ID>", "<SECRET>");

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://MyVault.vault.azure.net/"), credential);
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("MySecret");
```

However I need it to run in a .NET Framework 4.7.1, the call eventually times out after retrying 4 times.

I fully suspect this is down to the corporate proxy I work behind (although if there may be other reasons please tell me).

There is a `SecretClientOptions` that inherits from `ClientOptions` which contains a `Transport` property but it is not immediately obvious how to use this.

I see on other versions of the [Node SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-secrets/secretclientoptions?view=azure-node-preview#proxyOptions) they have a `proxyOptions` property but that doesn't exist in the .NET version. Is there another way to configure this?

I also wanted to try an diagnose a bit further but am not sure how to use the `Diagnostics` property and I struggle to get Fiddler to capture any .NET traffic these days.

**UPDATE**: Looks like a fix for this was committed 9 days ago so expecting a fix soon which will make .NET Framework use the system proxy correctly - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/16990

Comment: Normally a proxy issue the error will occur in 30 seconds.  So setting the client.Proxy = null stops the search for the proxy.  The issue may also be a TLS version.  So adding to code the following sometimes helps : System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.  You and also add support for TLS13 by or'ing the two.  Old version of Net do not have the enumeration so you need to use the number instead.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0

Comment: Check out this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#access-your-secrets-aspnet

Comment: @jdweng I don't see any Proxy property on the SecretClient. The TLS was a good shout but didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into the library code it appears that the normal proxy as used with HttpClient isn't used. By setting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables I was able to get this to work.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://my.corporate.proxy/");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://my.corporate.proxy/");
```

**UPDATE**: Looks like a fix for this was committed 9 days ago so expecting a fix soon which will make .NET Framework use the system proxy correctly - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/16990

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution here can be the answer by *Mun* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542344/azure-key-vault-secret-access-intermittently-failing-to-connect-with-socket-exce). He suggests to cache the Key Vault values in App Settings Data structure.

You can also try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#access-your-secrets-aspnet) approach suggested by Docs if you don't prefer above approach.

Comment: The caching is exactly what I am trying to do however I couldn't get access to the key vault even once. I would use the second app settings method but I need to fit into a bespoke settings provider the company has used for years